# how can i make a loop in which each time new variable can be made on each processing of loop

Tags: c, loops, variables, variable-declaration

So I was working on some question practice and there I came to a need to create a new variable on each processing of loop like
(str_i) where (i) will be given as 1,2,3... I also made a code but I wasn't able to do this....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
    {
        int i,M,N;
        char a[20];
        printf("enter the n. of string you want to be processed=");
        scanf("%d",&N);


        char str;
        for (i=1;i<=N;i++)
            {
                scanf("%s",a);
                printf("%s \n",a);
                /*Now here i want to create a new variable for 
                each iteration like str_1,str_2..... and so on*/

            }


    }
```

Comment: Do you know about [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) already and using arrays of pointers?

Comment: "*don't take it seriously*" - If we don't take it seriously, how should we be able to write serious answers then?

Comment: actually NO, i don't know and even i didn't get the below given answers....just waiting for any another good answer....that may help me..

Comment: i wanted to said that the code i had written doesn't work for my question in any situation but i just wrote it to give a idea for readers that what i want to know....as you know just for reference..that's why i wrote "don't take it seriously".

Comment: Your example asks the user to input a number of strings but since the amount is fixed then, why do you need to create a new variable/storage place in each iteration then? I guess the example is a little flawed.

Comment: #RobertS is it ok now? i edited my question so that it will be more understandable..

Answer (score 1):

That's called an array: Since you already know the number of loop runs in advance, you can create an array with a fixed size in advance and then fill it in the loop:

```c
char **str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * N);
```

if you want to read in strings, you have to reserve additional storage space in each iteration

```c
str[i] = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
```

and copy the content from your buffer `a` into:

```c
strcpy(str[i], a);
```

Since your buffer is only 20 bytes long, you should also limit the input to 19 characters (1 byte is required for the final zero character):

```c
scanf("%19s", a);
```

Otherwise this could lead to a buffer overflow.

Comment: What you show in the code is not an array. You just just a malloced memory like an array.

Comment: `str[i] = malloc(strlen(a));` is wrong. It should be `str[i] = malloc(strlen(a)+1);` in order to allocating for terminating null-character.

Comment: `char *str = malloc(sizeof(char*) * N);` is also wrong. It should be `char **str = malloc(sizeof(char*) * N);` in order to store pointers as elements of the array.

Comment: Should the memory be statically allocated or come from the stack to be called so? Dynamic arrays are also allocated first.

Comment: `char **str = malloc(sizeof(char*) * N);` is considered a bad practice. It should be char **str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * N);